# Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined after new function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to really find the source of this error. I solved it temporary the other day but it seems that everytime i add a new function in  the JS file i keep getting that. Before i would only get "Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined" on only the new function but now it's for all of them. I also get a "ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " but that's a secondary problem at least for now.

index file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-draw.js"></script>
</head>
<h2>Players</h2>
<div class="players">
<script>
  setInterval( refreshPlayers, 5000 );
  var inRequest = false;
</script></div>
<h3>Please select the Game you would like to view</h3>
<div class="pickGame">
<script>
  setInterval( viewGames, 5000 );
  var inRequestT = false;
</script>
</div>
<h2>Game</h2>
<div class="agonas">
<script>
  setInterval( refreshAgonas, 5000);
  var inRequestG = false;
</script></div>
</html>
```

jquery-draw.js file

```
function viewGames(){
    if ( inRequestT ) {
      return false;
    }
    inRequestT = true;
    var load = $.get('drawgames.php');
    $(".pickGame").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".pickGame").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".pickGame").html('<form method="post" action="viewgame.php">
<select name="gameNo">'+res+'</select>
<input type="submit" value="Choose Game">
</form>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
      inRequestT = false;
    });
}
function refreshAgonas() {
    if ( inRequestG ) {
      return false;
    }
    inRequestG = true;
    var load = $.get('playersdata.php');
    $(".agonas").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".agonas").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".agonas").html('<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>League</th><th>Sex</th><th>Birthday</th></tr>'+res+'</table>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
      inRequestG = false;
    });
  }
function refreshPlayers() {
    if ( inRequest ) {
      return false;
    }
    inRequest = true;
    var load = $.get('playersdata.php');
    $(".players").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".players").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".players").html('<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>League</th><th>Sex</th><th>Birthday</th></tr>'+res+'</table>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
      inRequest = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: *"I also get a "ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " but that's a secondary problem"* No, it isn't.

Comment: even if i change that and but something else in the output for the pickGame i still get the reference error.

Comment: It makes no sense to have your script file rely on variables that it doesn't define. Put your `var inRequest = false;` and such *in* `jquery-draw.js` (probably at the top).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
      $(".pickGame").html('<form method="post" action="viewgame.php">
<select name="gameNo">'+res+'</select>
<input type="submit" value="Choose Game">
</form>');
```

JavaScript doesn't allow raw newlines in strings unless you escape them with a backslash. If you have them there, the entire script can't be parsed, and nothing will work.

Separately, you're doing this:

```
var load = $.get('drawgames.php');
```

and then calling the functions `error`, `success`, and `done` on `load`. `load` will refer to a jqXHR object. They don't have `error` or `success` functions (they do have a `done` function). You're confusing the *properties* that the `$.ajax` function accepts for callbacks and the functions provided by `jqXHR`. I recommend [reviewing the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for the correct way to use `$.get`.

Comment: Looks like the `error` `success` and `done` and i'll have to use `done` `fail` and `always`. I'll take a deeper look now but i don't get it since it was working fine before adding another function. Now i've corrected the token error but i think it's messing with me. Still getting the error in browser. Would you mind spending a couple of minutes in chat?

Answer (score 0):

This all needs to be on one line:

```
      $(".pickGame").html('<form method="post" action="viewgame.php">
<select name="gameNo">'+res+'</select>
<input type="submit" value="Choose Game">
</form>');
```